# I want to see the list of all dbus interfaces with a command in terminal .h

Tags: linux, d-bus

I know how to get the list of all services in dbus but then I want to see the list of interfaces inside each service.

```
dbus-send --session           \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
  --type=method_call          \
  --print-reply               \
  /org/freedesktop/DBus       \
  org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

This gives a list of all available services.

Answer (score 1):

There are several utilities to handle doing this recursively for you but assuming all you have is dbus-send you can still accomplish what you are trying to do with the following:

Take the list of services and for the ones you are interested denoted by $SERVICE in run:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=${SERVICE} --type=method_call --print-reply "/" org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

This will give you something like:

```
method return time=1563564828.143670 sender=:1.107 -> destination=:1.13227 serial=167 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<!-- GDBus 2.58.3 -->
<node>
  <node name="org"/>
</node>
"
```

For each node node you can run the command again for the subpath so for NODE_PATH=/org

```
dbus-send --session --dest=${SERVICE} --type=method_call --print-reply "${NODE_PATH}" org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

You would get another set of nodes with which you can repeat the process until you finally get to the interfaces which list the methods. Here is an example:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply "/org/freedesktop" org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect      
method return time=1563565305.203169 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.13267 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus">
    <method name="Hello">
      <arg direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="RequestName">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="in" type="u"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="u"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ReleaseName">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="u"/>
    </method>
    <method name="StartServiceByName">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="in" type="u"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="u"/>
    </method>
    <method name="UpdateActivationEnvironment">
      <arg direction="in" type="a{ss}"/>
    </method>
    <method name="NameHasOwner">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="b"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ListNames">
      <arg direction="out" type="as"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ListActivatableNames">
      <arg direction="out" type="as"/>
    </method>
    <method name="AddMatch">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="RemoveMatch">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetNameOwner">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ListQueuedOwners">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="as"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetConnectionUnixUser">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="u"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetConnectionUnixProcessID">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="u"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetAdtAuditSessionData">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="ay"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetConnectionSELinuxSecurityContext">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="ay"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ReloadConfig">
    </method>
    <method name="GetId">
      <arg direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetConnectionCredentials">
      <arg direction="in" type="s"/>
      <arg direction="out" type="a{sv}"/>
    </method>
    <property name="Features" type="as" access="read">
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal" value="const"/>
    </property>
    <property name="Interfaces" type="as" access="read">
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal" value="const"/>
    </property>
    <signal name="NameOwnerChanged">
      <arg type="s"/>
      <arg type="s"/>
      <arg type="s"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="NameLost">
      <arg type="s"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="NameAcquired">
      <arg type="s"/>
    </signal>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable">
    <method name="Introspect">
      <arg direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer">
    <method name="GetMachineId">
      <arg direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Ping">
    </method>
  </interface>
  <node name="DBus"/>
</node>
"
```